# Is it possible to upload multiple files in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I need a component where user can click on browse button and select multiple files using ctrl key and upload them at once. Please note that it is dfferent from clicking add more files each time a file gets uploaded.

Is it posible in flex ? Does anyone has any idea in this regard ?

Thanks in advance.

Ashine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another component for your reference:
http://weblog.cahlan.com/2006/12/flex-upload-component.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed it is. There is even a good working example here: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Multiple_file_upload-6742.html